# when does Nginx have unexpected write on disk?

Tags: nginx, hard-drive, kubernetes

I use Nginx to cache static files. the main problem is sudden changes on write on the disk.

`nginx.conf`:

```
http {
    proxy_cache_path /cache-data levels=2:2:2 keys_zone=images_cache:60000m inactive=2d use_temp_path=off;


    server {
        access_log off;
        listen 8080 reuseport;

        location ~ ^/storage(\d+)?\.my-domain\.com/ {
            # Configure the proxy cache
            proxy_cache images_cache;
            proxy_cache_background_update on;
            proxy_cache_lock on;
            proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 2d;
    }
}
```

the main problem:
[image]
this is a report of node exporter of Kubernetes (I have only an Nginx on this node)

I know:

- the read rate on the disk is not changed.
- the request rate is not changed.
- the hit/miss/stale rate is not changed.
- the volume size is not changed.
- the access_log is disabled.

some update:

- ram: 60GB
- capacity of the pod (`cache-data`): more than 200GB

Comment: You've tagged this kubernetes yet fail to mention how it is involved in your question. Care to clarify?

Comment: `keys_zone=images_cache:60000m` - could you please clarify what do you think this directive does, what is the amount of memory available for pod,  and what is the size of cache directory so far ?